# How can I turn off the realtime display of unix command "top"?

Tags: top

I want `top` to just give me the results when I call it and then exit. How can this be done?

`top`'s [manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top) does not list any flag for this purpose.

Also, I do not want to use `ps -eLf` for the purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `top` [manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top):

> ```
> -n : Number of iterations limit as:  -n number
>         Specifies the maximum number of iterations,
>         or frames, top should produce before ending.
> ```

So just run:

```
top -n 1
```